How to return multiple columns from one function inside `mutate` and allow me to name the output columns?
Consider this code:
library(dplyr)
a = data.frame(a = 1:3)
abc = \(x) data.frame(x/2, x/3)
a %>% 
  mutate(abc(a))

which returns
  a x.2       x.3
1 1 0.5 0.3333333
2 2 1.0 0.6666667
3 3 1.5 1.0000000

but I don't have control over the names as I want to assign them something else.
One way to solve this is to the return type of abc to be named but this is not ideal as I may want to run abc on two sets of variables
a %>% 
  mutate(abc(a), abc(b))

The other way is of course is to rename them after each run of abc but then that could be unstable.
Is there to way to give names to the output of abc? e.g.
a %>% 
  mutate(c("a1","a2") := abc(a), c("b1","b2") := abc(b))

But the above := syntax didn't work.

This feels weird to me; like you might be better off restructuring your data first, but without more context, I can't say for sure.
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)
abc <- \(x) data.frame(x/2, x/3)

df %>%
  mutate(
    abc(a) %>% setNames(c("a1", "a2")),
    abc(b) %>% setNames(c("b1", "b2"))
  )

##   a b  a1        a2  b1       b2
## 1 1 4 0.5 0.3333333 2.0 1.333333
## 2 2 5 1.0 0.6666667 2.5 1.666667
## 3 3 6 1.5 1.0000000 3.0 2.000000


This is the closest in spirit to what they seem to be looking for, nicely done.

1) Try the .unpack= argument of across .  Here abc is the unmodified function in the question.
namefn <- function(prefix, x) paste0(prefix, seq_along(x))
a %>%
  mutate(across(a, abc, .unpack = "{namefn('a', inner)}"),
         across(a, abc, .unpack = "{namefn('b', inner)}"))
##   a  a1        a2  b1        b2
## 1 1 0.5 0.3333333 0.5 0.3333333
## 2 2 1.0 0.6666667 1.0 0.6666667
## 3 3 1.5 1.0000000 1.5 1.0000000

or perhaps this variation:
a %>%  mutate(b = a, across(a:b, abc, .unpack = "{outer}{seq_along(inner)}"))
##   a b  a1        a2  b1        b2
## 1 1 1 0.5 0.3333333 0.5 0.3333333
## 2 2 2 1.0 0.6666667 1.0 0.6666667
## 3 3 3 1.5 1.0000000 1.5 1.0000000

2) If names of the form prefix.1, prefix.2, ...  (which are almost the same as the question's names) are suitable then use with/cbind instead of mutate as shown.   If there is a pattern to the names that could be programmed into abc2 as well.
a %>%
  with(cbind(., a = unname(abc(a)), b = unname(abc(a))))
##   a a.1       a.2 b.1       b.2
## 1 1 0.5 0.3333333 0.5 0.3333333
## 2 2 1.0 0.6666667 1.0 0.6666667
## 3 3 1.5 1.0000000 1.5 1.0000000

3) Another approach is to create a one line wrapper around abc which adds the names not provided by or incorrectly provided by abc. It can be used in either of the two forms shown below expressing the mutate compactly while allowing abc to remain as is without modification.
abc2 <- function(x, ...) setNames(abc(x), c(...))
a %>% 
  mutate( abc2(a, "a1", "a2"), abc2(a, c("b1", "b2")) )
##   a  a1        a2  b1        b2
## 1 1 0.5 0.3333333 0.5 0.3333333
## 2 2 1.0 0.6666667 1.0 0.6666667
## 3 3 1.5 1.0000000 1.5 1.0000000


One option would be to add an optional argument to name the output and/or set the names of the output based on the name of the input column, e.g. something like:
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

a <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)

abc <- \(x, .names = NULL) {
  if (is.null(.names)) .names <- paste0(deparse(substitute(x)), 1:2)
  setNames(data.frame(x / 2, x / 3), .names)
}

a %>%
  mutate(abc(a))
#>   a b  a1        a2
#> 1 1 4 0.5 0.3333333
#> 2 2 5 1.0 0.6666667
#> 3 3 6 1.5 1.0000000

a %>%
  mutate(abc(a, c("ab", "ba")))
#>   a b  ab        ba
#> 1 1 4 0.5 0.3333333
#> 2 2 5 1.0 0.6666667
#> 3 3 6 1.5 1.0000000

a %>%
  mutate(abc(a), abc(b))
#>   a b  a1        a2  b1       b2
#> 1 1 4 0.5 0.3333333 2.0 1.333333
#> 2 2 5 1.0 0.6666667 2.5 1.666667
#> 3 3 6 1.5 1.0000000 3.0 2.000000


This feels like it matches the R idiom well, as the function now returns the object you actually want. In the original version, the abc has names that don't match what you want them to be.

Perhaps a custom mutate function? Though I'd prefer anjama's solution personally, which does practically the same thing but within the regular mutate.
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)
abc <- \(x) data.frame(x/2, x/3)

mutate_name <- function(.data, expr, names) {
  value <- setNames(eval(substitute(expr), .data), names)
  mutate(.data, value)
}

dat |> 
  mutate_name(abc(a), c("a1", "a2")) |>
  mutate_name(abc(b), c("b1", "b2"))


##   a b  a1        a2  b1       b2
## 1 1 4 0.5 0.3333333 2.0 1.333333
## 2 2 5 1.0 0.6666667 2.5 1.666667
## 3 3 6 1.5 1.0000000 3.0 2.000000


Here is just a base R option, where you can use lapply with unname + as.data.frame to achieve your objective, simply
> cbind(a, as.data.frame(lapply(a, \(x) unname(abc(x)))))
  a b a.1       a.2 b.1      b.2
1 1 4 0.5 0.3333333 2.0 1.333333
2 2 5 1.0 0.6666667 2.5 1.666667
3 3 6 1.5 1.0000000 3.0 2.000000

data
> dput(a)
structure(list(a = 1:3, b = 4:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))


Maybe mutate isn't the right way to do this.  Why not use bind_cols() and rename()?
library(dplyr)

abc <- \(x) data.frame(x/mean(x), x/median(x))

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  bind_cols(
    abc(.$Petal.Width) %>% rename(PW_1 = 1, PW_2 = 2),
    abc(.$Sepal.Width) %>% rename(SW_1 = 1, SW_2 = 2))

(group_by added just to prove this works even with grouped data)
